# How to programmatically display current test number in Node.js Mocha test suite?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I currently have a test suite that I execute and see something like:

```
/path/to/test/test.js
    ✓ test passed
    ✓ test passed
    ✓ test passed (356ms)

/path/to/test/testing.js
    ✓ test passed (200ms)
    ✓ test passed (356ms)
    ✓ test passed (325ms)

6 passing (1m)
```

I have several hundred tests, so I wanted to see if there was a way to print what test the process is currently at, at the very least after each test file, e.g.

```
/path/to/test/test.js
    ✓ test passed
    ✓ test passed
    ✓ test passed (356ms)

    3/6 tests completed

/path/to/test/testing.js
    ✓ test passed (200ms)
    ...
```

Is this possible? I was thinking describing hooks might work, but don't see a concrete indication that this is the case:

https://mochajs.org/#describing-hooks

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own [reporter](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/wiki/Third-party-reporters) that does that, or you can check, on npm, if someone already did that for you.

Something like the following should do the trick:

```
var passes = 0;
var failures = 0;

runner.on('pass', function(test){
  passes++;
  console.log(`${test.fullTitle()} passed`);
});

runner.on('fail', function(test, err){
  failures++;
});

runner.on('suite end', function () {
  console.log(`${passes}/${failures} tests completed`);
});
```

Comment: humm, i have a reporter already, but I use that to create a report that is readable by our business users, and I just want something printing to the terminal when I run the `mocha` command. If this is the only way, then it might not be possible for my needs.

Comment: Not sure if I follow then. Reporters do whatever you need, including printing to the terminal. And your terminal printing reporter can be used via the `--reporter` option with the `mocha` command.

Comment: I am running my test suite like shown in https://mochajs.org/#getting-started, so I run `mocha` and all the tests files in `test` get executed, and mocha just automatically prints which tests passed, I do not run the reporter for this. However, I do have a reported that I run, but that is to create a pretty report, not for my purposes.